# How to use Eclipse for Spring REST development with Brackets like editor for JavaScript/front end development?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, rest, adobe-brackets

We have two separate web projects for our application

- One for Spring REST services
- Other for AngularJS, the front end of the application.

We have been using eclipse for development of both and also for running those locally on tomcat server.

It is a great deal of pain to view updates to JavaScript and CSS part of the second project from eclipse, because it requires restart or publish of the tomcat server every time which takes a long time.

So I wanted to use eclipse for development of REST and front-end development editor like Brackets for development of AngularJS/JavaScript and CSS. But then they run on different ports causing Cross Site requests errors, and I don't want to write any CORS filter like [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) for this purpose.

Is there any better way to get these tools work together ?

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Tool Suite](http://spring.io/tools) (STS) uses the pivotal tc server will automatically deploy resources without redeploying the application.  Download it and give it a go,  STS is just eclipse anyway with different branding.  Maybe you can just download it, copy the pivotal server folder to your eclipse folder and add it to your servers view in your eclipse version.  One thing I have noticed is that the application must be running under a context for this to work, deploying to root does not automatically deploy resources for some reason (at least this was the case when I was using the previous vfabric server about a year ago).